# Interpolation methods for radar and acoustic imaging and potential pitfalls

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, interpolation, radar, spatial

A) What are the most common methods used to remap data for current generation imaging radars and acoustic sensors?

B) What are some of the pitfalls in these methods?

For example, in the past,  at least, cubic splines have been used to map slant-range image data from synthetic aperture radar to a uniform "ground" grid. This can introduce spurious signals in ocean wave spectra.